# mozilla nss bltest failed

Tags: fips, nss

I built nss package from source and then ran

```
bltest -F
```

(FIPS test) on my CentOS 7. It failed. Traced the code, I found it failed in:

```
blapi_SHVerifyFile(const char *shName, PRBool self)
```

because it cannot find:

```
Linux3.10_x86_64_cc_glibc_PTH_64_DBG.OBJ/bltest.chk
```

Any one can give me a pointer what is the `bltest.chk` file and why it is or it is not there?

Thanks